# How to prevent refreshing of a page through Javascript/jQuery/ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, event-handling, dom-events

The following code is running but I want to stop the browser refresh. By using `onbeforeunload()`, its detecting everything like closing the tab, clicking on another link etc. But I want to detect the browser click. So how to do that?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">             
onbeforeunload=function(){
return false;           //This is showing a pop up, which should not come.
}

if (document.addEventListener) {            \\adding event listener
        document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
} 

else {
        document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
        window.event.returnValue = false;
        });
}

document.onkeydown = function() {    //switch case to detect refresh from keyboard
switch (event.keyCode) { 
    case 116 :                      //F5 button
        event.returnValue = false;
        event.keyCode = 0;
        return false; 
    case 82 :                       //Ctrl+R button
        if (event.ctrlKey) { 
            event.returnValue = false; 
            event.keyCode = 0;  
            return false; 
        } 
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>name: <input type="text"></input></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ajax does not refresh page

Comment: Indeed, where is the ajax here?.  Also preventing people from refreshing the page I think is something you cannot stop.

Comment: You can't prevent visitors to refresh/leave a page.

Comment: User could still press enter in adress bar anyway...

Comment: can I use TYPE_RELOAD to detect if the user want to refresh? if yes, then please tell me how?

Comment: At that stage the page in the client's machine is already gone, both `beforeunload` and `unload` events have fired. Once again, there's no way to prevent user to refresh the page, this is for security reasons. If you need to preserve some JS values or HTML state after refresh, use for example `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` to maintain values. Or send them to your server with (blocking) AJAX request in `beforeunload`, and restore them when creating the server response.